# Giving scatter points different color on each continent [Python]

Tags: python, global, matplotlib-basemap, scatter, labeling

I'm stuck already for a couple of hours on a task.

I have an excel-file with all cities with 300000+ habitants + coordinates. I have to plot them on a global map. For this I have the following code:

```
from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().magic('reset -sf') 
get_ipython().magic('matplotlib')
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
plt.close('all')
#%%
dirname=('C:\\Users\\Guido\\Documents\\Geologie\\Programmeren\\Scripts van mij\\Deftig\\')
filename='WUP2014-F12-Cities_Over_300K.xls'
xlsfile = pd.ExcelFile(dirname + filename)
drframe = xlsfile.parse("DATA", skiprows = 16)
urbpop = DataFrame(drframe)
lat = urbpop["Latitude"]
lon = urbpop["Longitude"]
m = Basemap(projection='robin',lon_0=0,resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries()
lons,lats = m(list(lon), list(lat))
m.scatter(lons, lats, s = 1.3, color ='blue')
```

[The excel-file looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/111hE.jpg)

[The output figure looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJzxv.jpg)

Now I have to give the points on each continent another color (so for instance South-America orange, Europe blue...).

Also I have to label each point with its amount of inhabitants.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should somehow provide continent information to excel file as a different column or you can create your own file, say continent.dat in json format or something.

```
{ 'south-america': ['Argentina', ,'Brazil', ...],
  'north-america': ['Canada', 'United States', ...],
  ... 
}
```

With this information, you can regroup your population dataframe data. Once you have done that then, you can follow your process for each continent by assigning different color.

Pandas groupby can be a good method if you want to add continent information to the excel file.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

Comment: I used your method and it works, thanks! However, I still need to be able to give each point a label (the amount of habitants). This is also a column in my excel file, but I don 't know how I can put this into practice. Any suggestions?

Comment: use plot.text(x, y, 'your text'). The x and y point should have some offset(in projected coordinated ) from the point plotted. Otherwise it will be written right on top of the text.